# Laravel docker image cannot find driver for pgsql

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

Firstly, I want to clarify that I have already conducted thorough research on StackOverflow and other resources to find a solution for my problem. Despite finding similar questions, I have not been able to find a solution that works for me. Therefore, I believe that my issue may not be a duplicate and I appreciate any assistance in resolving it.

I am running a Laravel project using `pgsql` as the `DB_CONNECTION` driver. When building and running the image locally with all the required ENV variables, including `DB_CONNECTION`, I can successfully connect to my remote RDS database. However, when building it from Github Actions and running it with ECS, it results in a `500 (Internal Server Error)` with no logs being shown in the response or generated in either `storage/logs/laravel.log` or CloudWatch.

I have added some debugging routes to the API:

A route that returns all environment variables available and all of the required variables in .env are listed with their expected values.
Another route that just returns the DB_CONNECTION driver value, which correctly returns "pgsql".
A third route that returns the `phpinfo()`, which shows that `pdo` and `pdo_pgsql` are installed.
Despite this, Laravel still throws the error "could not find driver" which this time I was able to catch adding `dd($e->getMessage());` into `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`'s reportable callback.

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM composer:2 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN set -ex && \
    composer install \
    --no-scripts \
    --no-autoloader \
    --ansi \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-dev && \
    composer dump-autoload

FROM php:8.1-alpine3.17

ENV PHP_VERSION=81

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    curl \
    nginx \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-fpm \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-ctype \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-curl \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-dom \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-gd \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-intl \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-mbstring \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-opcache \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-openssl \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-phar \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-session \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-xml \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-xmlreader \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-pdo \
    php${PHP_VERSION}-pdo_pgsql \
    libpq-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql

RUN adduser -S www-data && \
    addgroup -S www-data && \
    addgroup www-data www-data && \
    addgroup www-data nginx

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build --chown=www-data:www-data /app .

RUN chmod -R 775 storage bootstrap/cache

RUN mkdir -p \
    /var/lib/nginx/tmp \
    /var/log/nginx \
    /var/log/php${PHP_VERSION}

RUN touch /run/nginx.pid

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data \
    /var/lib/nginx/tmp \
    /var/log/nginx \
    /var/log/php${PHP_VERSION} \
    /run/nginx.pid

USER www-data

COPY docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY docker/php/fpm/www.conf /etc/php${PHP_VERSION}/php-fpm.d/www.conf

RUN php artisan optimize

EXPOSE 8000

# I was using supervisor but removed it for testing
CMD ["sh", "-c", "nginx -g 'daemon off;' & php-fpm81 -F"]
```

I have no idea what may be causing this error. I don't know if Laravel has another driver along with the Database driver and this is in fact what is missing.

Can someone please help me figure out what's causing this error?

Comment: Try checking the `DB_HOST` in your .env file

Comment: The DB_HOST and some other required env vars exists and are accessible via $_ENV or $_SERVER. I think the problem isn’t the env variables since I can connect to the database running the image locally. I only get this error running the image built from GitHub Actions with ECS.

Comment: If you build the image locally and it has the driver, and you build the image on GitHub and it does NOT have the driver, then there has to be something broken in the build process on GitHub. I suggest trying to download the image built by GitHub, and run it locally to verify that is the actual issue.

Comment: @MarkB I did it and the problem is the same. Seems like the environment variables are not being loaded somehow. If you call env('DB_CONNECTION') then you have `pgsql` but if you try to connect to the DB it says "could not find driver". The same happens if you try to run `php artisan migrate`. The problem occurs via php-fpm or cli.

Comment: I think the solution will be for me to stop relying on the server env vars and make or pull a `.env` during the container startup. I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a solution to this problem yet, but I made it work by downloading a `.env` file containing all necessary env vars from S3 during image startup as a temporary solution and adding S3 reading permission to the task execution role.